# Transcendence of the rational powers of $\pi$?

Tags: reference-request, pi, transcendental-numbers

> What is known about transcendence of the numbers of the form ${\pi}^{r}$ where $r \in \mathbb Q \setminus \{0,1\}$?  For which $r$ are they proven to be transcendental?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of them.

If $\theta=\pi^{a/b}$ is algebraic then so is $\theta^b = \pi^a$ and so is $\pi$.